# Text watermark on webpage

Tags: html, css, watermark

I want to create a **TEXT** watermark on web page.

The **text** of the watermark will be dynamic.

Is there any way I can make a watermark for a web page?

Comment: If you show us the code that you currently have, it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just position:fixed a text element to the page bottom right corner.

Comment: thanks ...<p style='position:fixed; color: #d0d0d0;font-size: 70pt;-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);left:center;'>Test Water mark</p>

Comment: How can we set text at it look like backgroaund text for water mark?

Comment: You can try to set color attribute to any rgba(x,x,x,opacity) value with partial transparency to acheive that.